# Error processing package python3-pip

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg

After an sudo apt full-upgrade or apt install -f I got the following error:

```
   loo# sudo apt full-upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
    4 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/384 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [O/n] O
    dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
     package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
     reinstall it before attempting configuration
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-aptdaemon:
     python3-aptdaemon depends on python3-apt (>= 0.8.5~ubuntu1); however:
      Package python3-apt is not configured yet.
    
    dpkg: error processing package python3-aptdaemon (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: error processing package python3-pip (--configure):
     package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
     reinstall it before attempting configuration
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aptdaemon:
     aptdaemon depends on python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu32.3); however:
      Package python3-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
    
    dpkg: error processing package aptdaemon (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     python3-apt
     python3-aptdaemon
     python3-pip
     aptdaemon
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Some info; loo# dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

Update1: When I run sudo apt install --reinstall python3-apt

Here's what I got:

```
dpkg: warning: old python3-apt package pre-removal script subprocess returned er
ror exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apt_2.0.1ubuntu0.
20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3-apt package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit statu
s 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apt_2.0.1ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure): package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration`: A simple read of the error message (which is in plain language) suggests trying `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-apt`

Comment: Please provide release details; your package implies *focal* but if that's not what you're using that is key detail as to reason. Packages are built for specific releases, thus release is required for *almost* anything package related (exceptions are *snap* packages for example)

Comment: @user535733 I just updated my question, still getting errors

Comment: `py3clean: not found`. Seems some unrevealed catastrophe happened to your system. the fastest recovery for somebody with your skills is to backup your data and reinstall. If you want to repair in order to learn, then can help you best if we don't need to guess what you are recovering from.